# I can not store something into a list at a specific index (IndexError: list assignment index out of range)

Tags: python

I convert the image into numpy array and split it into four parts. Now I want to store those 4 NumPy arrays in another array so that I can retrieve those arrays from index number and perform further processing on each part. Here is the block of code:

```py
img = Image.open('topsecret1.jpg')
# get width and height
width = img.width
height = img.height
n=4
arr=[]
widthDiv = int(width/4)
widthDiv1 = widthDiv
heightDiv = int(height/4)
heightDiv1 = heightDiv
initialw = 0
initialh = 0
oriImg = cv2.imread('topsecret1.jpg')
b = np.array(oriImg)
for i in range(0,n):
    for x in range(0, height):
        if (height >= heightDiv):
            for y in range(0, width):
                if (width >= widthDiv):
                    arr[i] = oriImg[initialw:widthDiv, initialh:heightDiv]
                    np.shape(arr[i])
                    cv2.imshow(f" part 1", arr[i])
                    cv2.waitKey()
                    widthDiv = widthDiv + widthDiv1
                    heightDiv = heightDiv + heightDiv1
                    initialw = initialw + initialw
                    initialh = initialh + initial
```

This is the error I receive:

```py
  arr[i] = oriImg[initialw:widthDiv, initialh:heightDiv]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: `arr=[]` is not an array, it’s a list. It has 0 elements, so `arr[i]` is out of bounds for any `i`. But you could do `arr.append(…)`. Please read the documentation on Python lists.

Answer (score 0):

You declared *arr* as an empty list. But you are trying to store values in it.
You have to create it with a size or add a new row before you want to access/store value from the array.

```
arr = [None]*n
```